# Getting Sending Failed Error while sending pdf through my app to whatsapp in android 11

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-11, file-sharing

Sending pdf files from my app to whatsapp was working until it was used on android 11 device
I have added      this permission also and have asked for runtime permission

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
                if (isPermissonGranted()){
                    Log.i("storageproblem","app runtime permission granted");
                    Uri fileuri = Uri.parse("file://" + file);
                    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileuri);
                    share.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                    share.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    share.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                    share.setType("*/*");
                    startActivity(share);
                }else{
                    Log.i("storageproblem","app runtime permission not granted");
                    takePermisson();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
Uri fileUri = Uri.parse("file://" + file);
```

use

```
Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "com.example.packagename.fileprovider", file);
```

Comment: its working , thank  you

Answer (score 1):

> > Uri fileuri = Uri.parse("file://" + file);

Dont use a file uri but use a FileProvider to serve your file and can use a content scheme uri.

Comment: how i can get the file which is stored in folder salesinvoices

Comment: ??????? How would we know? But you can use the same `file` instance as you used before.

Comment: ??? I have no idea why you posted that last comment.

Comment: sorry but i have no idea why i cant share pdf  and also logcat is not showing any errors. it was a delivered project. please help it was working until today

Answer (score 0):

changing uri to file provider works

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30702554)